# how to check time between 7 00 and 18 00

Tags: python

i have problem with this script.

```
named_tuple = time.localtime()
time_string = time.strftime("%H:%M", named_tuple)

if time_string > "7:00" or time_string < "18:00":

    print("day")
else:
    print("evening")
```

how can I check day or evening please?

Comment: What is wrong with your current code? Seems fine to me.

Comment: The string-format `%H` will always represent the hour in 2 digits, so you should check against `07:00` and not `7:00`

Comment: You say you have a problem but you don't say what that problem is.

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the hour from what `time.localtime()` returns:

```
>>> time.localtime()
time.struct_time(tm_year=2019, tm_mon=6, tm_mday=12, tm_hour=19, tm_min=..., tm_sec=..., tm_wday=2, tm_yday=163, tm_isdst=...)
>>> _.tm_hour
19
```

Then you just compare `tm_hour` with the values you want:

```
Time = time.localtime()
if 7 <= Time.tm_hour <= 18:
    print('Yeah!')
```

If you need to be more precise, grab the minutes:

```
if (6, 45) <= (Time.tm_hour, Time.tm_min) <= (18, 5):
    ...
```

Comment: great. thank you very much. but I wrote just example. I compare 6:45 and 18:05 and it is not so easy for me

Answer (score 0):

Right now the first statement will always match. 
Your time will ALWAYS be greater than 7:00 OR less than 18:00.

Change `or` to `and` and it should work.

EDIT:
I had just glanced at the `if` statement briefly and noticed that it was broken. Fundamentally having the or in there will prevent the `else` statement from ever being executed. However, looking at it again, there are more errors going on than just the `or` issue.

Like @ForceBru mentions, you'll want to get the hour so that you're not doing a string comparison.

Comment: it is not true. i test it also with and and it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use your time_string to check if it's greater than "7:00" or smaller than "18:00", because it ranks strings according to alphanumerical order.
For example, it's now 12:32. The first character of my time_string would be "1", which is smaller than "7", so it would print "evening" even if it's noon.
Also, you want to check if it's later than 7:00 AND earlier than 18:00.
Maybe you can add more options too, because any time earlier than 7:00 would print "evening".
As for how to do it, see ForceBru's answer, which keeps it super simple.